# Override vb.net Function in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, overriding

I'm a little confused about this simply things. How Can I override vb.net Function in C#. I wrote this code in vb.net in vb.net class:

```
 Public Overridable Function Test1() As Integer
        Dim t1 As Integer
        Return t1
 End Function
```

I want to override this in C# class which inherits through vb.net class. Method code below.

```
    public override  int Test1()
    {
        int t1 = 2;
        return t1;
    }
```

I receive error: No suitable method to override.

Comment: Crystal ball says that you forgot to derive from the VB class.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this and it seems to work. My code:

```
Public Class TestClass
    Public Overridable Function Test() As Integer
        Dim t1 as Integer
        Return t1
    End Function
End Class
```

C#:

```
using MyVBProject;

public class CSharpClass : TestClass
{
    public override int Test()
    {
       int t1 = 2;
       return t1;
    }
}
```

some things to check:

- The C# project has a reference to the VB project
- The C# file is `using` the vb namespace
- The C# class does actually derive from the VB class `CSharpClass : TestClass`

Answer (score -1):

That can be because to put a public override, all class has to be public, instead, you can try to write "protected override" and not "public override". Otherwise, I think your question is alredy in stack overflow: [link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446007/c-sharp-no-suitable-method-found-to-override-but-there-is-one)